C++ DearImGUI Drag and Drop with personalized data type
I'm currently struggling with dragging and dropping textures from one ImGui window to another and rendering them there.
I'm storing all necessary data to render my texture in a struct called Texture::data, so that's what I'm trying to set as a payload for my drag and drop.
All available textures are displayed in an ImGui window and from there you should be able to drag them.
for (const auto& text : texts) {
   
            ImGui::ImageButton((void*)text.ID, ImVec2(buttonSize.x, buttonSize.y), {0,1}, {1,0});

            if(ImGui::BeginDragDropSource())
            {
                ImGui::SetDragDropPayload("TEXTURE", &text, sizeof(Texture::data));
                ImGui::EndDragDropSource();
            }
}

Then I have another ImGui panel for my viewport, where the texture can be dropped and the payload should be accepted.
        ImGui::Image((void*)2, ImVec2{windowSize.x, windowSize.y}, {0, 1}, {1, 0});

        if (ImGui::BeginDragDropTarget())
        {
            auto x = ImGui::AcceptDragDropPayload("TEXTURE");
            if (x)
            {
                auto* f = (Texture::data *) &x;
                std::cout << "DROPPED TEX: " << f->ID << '\n';
            }
            ImGui::EndDragDropTarget();
        }


However, when I try to access the data that has been dropped inside my viewport panel, I get weird values and also the same values for each texture, e.g. for the shown example 'f->ID' it prints "1065353216", where the ID should be an integer between 0 and 12 at the moment.
The drag panel and the drop panel are also in different classes, if that has something to do with it.
Am I missing something obvious here?

Understood. The question needs more meat to be answerable. Probably a [mre] will suffice. 1065353216 doesn't map to any magic debug number that I recognize. What is texts? Is it a vector or other container that could have been manipulated such that the pointer given to SetDragDropPayload has been invalidated or gone out of scope?

It is a vector of type Texture::data. I think it might be possible that it's an out of scope issue, but my brain is failing to know what to do with that information. Would it suffice to make it a pointer to a vector?
